# Can Wget return true or false (0 or 1)

Tags: linux, perl, unix, wget

hi everyone I relly want to know if wget can return true or false (0 or 1) only after processing certain url. My idea is to create a small PERL script to monitor few of my web pages and send email, or some kind of alert (I am still in dev process).
Here is what I have so far:

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use LWP::Simple;

my $url='google.com';

system('wget --delete -q $url');
print "$?";
if($? != 0 )
{
        print "false\n";
}

else
{
        print "OK\n";
}
```

This is just the beginning, but I am trying to make it as silent as possible, the lesser output the better.
This is my output now :
  Try `wget --help' for more options.
  256
  false
Any help will be appreciated. Also it does not have to be wget but this is what I know so far.

Comment: What version of wget are you using?  I don't see a `--delete` option in mine.

Comment: I am using one in UNIX and Ubuntu they both have --delete option it prevents from saving files in the directory. How to find out the wget ver. I have no idea

Answer (score 2):

`$url` is not interpolated in a single-quoted string literal, so you ran the shell command

```
wget --delete -q $url
```

Unless there is an environment variable `url`, this executes the command `wget` with the two parameters `--delete` and `-q`. Wget complains about a “Missing URL” (you omitted some of the error lines) and returns the status code 1.

The variable [`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables) contains the status code of the command, multiplied by 256. More precisely, it's the value returned by the [`wait` system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait). Having `$?` equal to zero does indicate success, you got that part right. Failure can be a code other than 1: any non-zero value indicates a failure.

If you want to see absolutely no output ever, redirect the output and the errors to `/dev/null`:

```
system("wget --delete -q $url >/dev/null 2>/dev/null");
```

But it's a bad idea to hide errors: if you do that, you can't diagnose them. You can quiet normal output without hiding errors by only redirecting stdout. But wget's `-q` option does this already.

```
system("wget --delete -q $url");
if ($?) {
    print "false\n";
} else {
    print "OK\n";
}
```

This code assumes that `$url` contains no shell special character. If you can't guarantee that, protect all shell special characters:

```
system('wget --delete -q ' . quotemeta($url) . ' >/dev/null 2>/dev/null');
```

or, if you aren't ignoring error messages, skip the shell altogether by using the multi-argument form of `system`:

```
system('wget', '--delete', '-q ', $url);
```

Comment: `quotemeta` is not the right tool for the job. It won't properly handle all characters. `system("... '$url');` is good enough for URLs, but if you want a generic solution, it's `use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote ); system(shell_quote('wget', '--delete', '-q', $url));`. Of course, you can avoids the need for the module by avoiding the shell entirely: `system('wget', '--delete', '-q', $url);`

Comment: @ikegami What character doesn't `quotemeta` handle properly (apart from newline)? You're right about the list form — I was going to use it, then wanted something simple that worked with the redirection, then moved things around to only mention quotemeta in the example without redirection and forgot to mention the list form — I'm adding it back.

Comment: Newline is that character. Before you say you'll never find that in a url, let me repeat you could have used `"'$url'"` rather than quotemeta if you're looking for a solution specific to urls (since urls can't have single-quotes).

Comment: @ikegami Newline isn't a valid character in URLs. `'` is (or at least, it's commonly typed that way, whereas newline isn't).

Comment: No, single quotes aren't valid, which is why you can safely embed URLs into HTML without escaping. (Not XHTML, though)